# Access nested output elements

Tags: r, shiny

I am planning a somewhat larger Shiny application and I wonder if there is a more structured way to access output elements from `shinyServer` than calling a unique `outputId`. My application could look like this:

```
library( shiny )
library( ggplot2 )

runApp( list(

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$explore_pca_main_projection_plot <- renderPlot({
      print( qplot( x = x, y = y, data = data.frame( x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10) ), geom="point" ) )
    })
  },

  ui = navbarPage( "MyApp",
    navbarMenu( "Explore",
      tabPanel( "PCA",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(),
          mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel( id = "explore_pca_main",
              tabPanel( "Projection", plotOutput( outputId = "explore_pca_main_projection_plot" ) ),
              tabPanel( "Loadings" ),
              tabPanel( "Variances" )
  ))))))

))
```

Is there no way to access the element `output$explore_pca_main_projection_plot` by it's hierarchy? I am thinking of something like

```
output$Explore$PCA$Projection$plotOutput[[1]]
```

A (working) solution similar to this would, at least, avoid to give a lot of outputId's being all redundant to the self-contained code.

Any help is appreciated.